# Access same field of every object in array of objects in mongodb aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I have the following documents in collection of mongodb:

```
banks:[{name:"ABC", amt:0},{name:"PQR", amt:-1},{name"XYZ", amt:3400}]

banks:[{name:"ABC", amt:-2},{name:"PQR", amt:2344},{name"XYZ", amt:7600}]
```

Like this say I have 10 documents and each document contains one banks array. Each banks array has 30 objects in it as shown above.

I am trying to write aggregation query in mongodb to get the count of objects that have "amt" less than equal to zero and greater than zero but so far unable to get it. Please help. Thanks in advance!

The output for above sample documents should be

```
{"greaterThanZero": 1, "lessThanEqualToZero": 2 }

{"greaterThanZero": 2, "lessThanEqualToZero": 1 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/),

- it checks condition using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) if match then add one to value,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      lessThanEqualToZero: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$banks",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $lte: ["$$this.amt", 0] },
              { $add: ["$$value", 1] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      greaterThanZero: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$banks",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $gt: ["$$this.amt", 0] },
              { $add: ["$$value", 1] },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7MyoLd0S0SO)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got my required results.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to separate yours documents with `$unwind`

Then with a `$project` and a `$cond` you tell for each document if it's `greaterThanZero` or `lessThanEqualToZero`

Finally you sum up `greaterThanZero` and `lessThanEqualToZero` with a `$group`

You can test it here : [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/THF2_WTk9nV)

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$banks"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "greaterThanZero": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$gt": [
              "$banks.amt",
              0
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      },
      "lessThanEqualToZero": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$lte": [
              "$banks.amt",
              0
            ]
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "greaterThanZero": {
        "$sum": "$greaterThanZero"
      },
      "lessThanEqualToZero": {
        "$sum": "$lessThanEqualToZero"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually unwinding will not work as I have to further process the counts per document.